# Show Msg when a cell reached determinated value

Tags: vba, excel

This is my VBA script for MS Excel

```
Sub Reached_150()

Dim cella As Range
Dim nomi As Range

For Each cella In [p2:p10]
    For Each nomi In [a2:a10]

    If cella.Value = 150 Then MsgBox "Lo studente " & nomi & " ha terminato le ore."
    Next nomi

Next cella

End Sub
```

In the Range p2:p10 I calculate the total,when the sum of the cell reaches 150 it displays the message that the student whose name is in column A has finished the hours.

About I have two questions:
1) As soon as the first cell reaches the end of 150 hours message appears for all the students' names, how can I avoid it?
2) How do I make the script automatically and not manually?
Waiting for answers thank anyone who can help me

Comment: Your second loop iterates all of the students' names, so if the cell value is 150, the message box will be called for each item (ie the names) in that loop. Presumably you want to capture one particular name, if so, which one?

Comment: only the name of which the corresponding cell containing the total reaches 150,example cells p2 reached 150 the msg show the name 
contained in the cell a2...
in practice every time that a cell reaches 150 show the msg

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely scenario is that you are trying to catch the name on the relevant row of the time cell.

If so, your code should be:

```
For Each cella In [p2:p10]
    If cella.Value = 150 Then MsgBox "Lo studente " & _
        cella.Offset(,-15).Value & " ha terminato le ore."

Next cella
```

Comment: It's work,but it's possible to make the automatic thing?, for now I call the script using alt + F8.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How are you updating the time value? Do you have a timer function of some kind, are the values entered by a user, etc? If you could let me know this, I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned what should happen if the value is greater that 150. If you specifically want 150 then remove the `>` from `">=150"` below.

To make it automatic use the `Worksheet_Change` event. Paste this in the Sheet code area.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    Set rng = Range("P2:P10")

    '~~> Check if there is any value >= 150 in that range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ">=150") Then
        For Each aCell In rng
            If aCell.Value >= 150 Then _
            MsgBox "Lo studente " & _
                   Range("A" & aCell.Row).Value & _
                   " ha terminato le ore."

        Next aCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This script does not work, just a cell reaches 150 nothing happen

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fJvGY.png

Comment: Why would you paste it in a module when I specifically said in the above post `Paste this in the Sheet code area.`

Comment: The script works only on the sheet where I have that data, but if the data I modify them through this transaction on another sheet, nothing appears.

Comment: The box of the sheet 1 the result is the proceeds of the circled cell value in sheet 2[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XDrKt.png